# View a ruler in Google Drawings

Tags: google-drawings

I am trying to draw an image as follows, using Google Drawings:

[image: Google Drawings image - trying to draw a grid]

I need these lines to be equidistant. Currently, I did that by using a square from top to first marking line. For this to be easy, I need rulers to left and top. For example see the following screenshot from Word:

[image: Word 2013 - with rulers on left and top]

Is there an option to turn on a ruler or something similar in Google Drawings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

Google Drawings doesn't have a ruler but it has "alignment, snap to grid and auto distribution" (see [2]) features. Alignment and distribution guides are automatically shown when the user moves one of the objects near to other objects that could used as reference to calculate the guides measures.

## Remarks

As far as I know it's not documented in the official help articles or they were removed while others still include links to them, i.e. "Snap to guides"

## References

- [1] [Docs editors help](http://support.google.com/docs)
- [2] [Paint and create charts and diagrams with Google Drawings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/177123?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a "Table" into the drawing, adjust the number of columns/rows until the cells are square, and use that as a guide.

Here, I took a screenshot while dragging the edge of the grey square. You can see the red "lineup" lines work with the table cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Chrome extension to get this functionality.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edge-the-web-ruler/njlkegdphefeellhaongiopcfgcinikh/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Right click on background then select Guides option from menu. You can select horizontal or vertical guides. Distance between these guides is measured using horizontal and vertical ruler (If not enabled in your case : Go to View -> Show ruler)

[Rectangle having 0.75 aspect ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itC0T.png)